# The regex I use doesn't allow symbols

Tags: c#, regex

```
regex = new Regex("(" + str1 + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I use this regular expressions to search the text with ignore case and substrings. But when I
I give symbols as input, I am getting a `ArgumentInvalid` exception. How can I allow this to search for symbols also? I am using this expression in C#.Net

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the regex.

Use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape)

Comment: He should write the code as follows - regex = new Regex("(" + Regex.Escape(str1) + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: Unless he wants to match the parentheses literally, in which case he should escape the whole thing. It doesn't really make much sense to enclose an entire regex in parentheses...